# Returning objects created within the called function's context

Tags: c++

I remember reading somewhere that we should avoid returning objects that are created locally within the called function (i.e. only dynamically allocated objects may be returned). However, I am not sure if that is sound advice because when dealing, for example, with overloaded operators we may have code like the following (taken from Object-Oriented Programming in C++ by Lafore, 4e) :

```
//
Distance operator+ (Distance d1, Distance d2) //add d1 to d2
{
  int f = d1.feet + d2.feet; //add the feet
  float i = d1.inches + d2.inches; //add the inches
  if(i >= 12.0) //if inches exceeds 12.0,
    { i -= 12.0; f++; } //less 12 inches, plus 1 foot
  return Distance(f,i); //return new Distance with sum
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Question:** What are the dos and don'ts for returning automatically allocated objects from a function?

Comment: I think you're confusing it with the problems explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: From the snippet, it's hard to infer whether returning a `Distance` object like this is fine or not - it depends on what the `Distance` constructor does, and how its signature looks like. If it copies the arguments and stores them in a `Distance` instance, it's fine. If it accepts the arguments by reference and stores references, you return an object that encapsulates dangling references.

Comment: @lubgr good point, but unlikely considering that the parameters are passed by value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I remember reading somewhere that we should avoid returning objects that are created locally within the called function (i.e. only dynamically allocated objects may be returned).

You remember wrong.

You should not return pointers or references to local objects:

```
int& foo() {
     int x = 42;
     return x; // DONT DO THIS
}
```

The returned reference is dangling. It refers to an `int` whose lifetime ended when the function returned. The function itself is kind of "ok", but the caller cannot read from the returned reference without invoking undefined behavior.

There is no problem with returning a copy of a local variable, other than a copy that you maybe can avoid, but that doesn't apply to `operator+`. Also there is RVO and copy elision (see [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)). In the code you posted the operator should take its parameters by `const&` to avoid a copy, but you cannot avoid creating a new instance, because the result needs to be stored somewhere.